# "since late on the previous evening"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, prepositional-phrases

I read this sentence in a book:

> He has been unconscious since late on the previous Saturday evening.

I am wondering about this construction. I thought it should be "since late the previous Saturday evening." Is the sentence from the book grammatical? Similar examples or reference to other pages would be very helpful.

Here's the original text:

[image]

Comment: Yes, "late on the previous evening" is not idiomatic.  Is this from a textbook or some other source?

Comment: @Andrew It's from [_Newton: A Very Short Introduction_](https://books.google.com/books?id=wtwSDAAAQBAJ&dq=newton+short+introduction&source=gbs_navlinks_s). I can totally see it used as a college science/philosophy textbook.

Comment: Is this from Isaac Newton's own writings then?  If so it may simply be archaic language, since Newton lived and wrote several hundred years ago.

Comment: @Andrew Nope. The author Rob Iliffe wrote it. I will snap a shot and put it up in the question.

Comment: It's a mystery to me then,  Perhaps he didn't have a very good editor?  But the context must be unusual, since it's written in the present perfect.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the additional context.  I see it's part of what I think is called a *participle phrase*.   It would have been fine if the author had left out the preposition entirely, *"Unconscious since late the previous Saturday evening"*.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound wrong to me [dialect: U.S. English]. To compare a simpler sentence:

- It happened **on** Saturday evening.

is quite natural. Note that it is not

- *It happened **in** Saturday evening.

though you would say "it happened **in** the evening."

Adding "late":

- It happened late **in**/***on** the evening.
- It happened late **on**/***in** Saturday evening.

But for

- It happened late **in**/**on** the Saturday evening.

I feel both are acceptable but with is a slightly different emphasis. Similarly:

- It happened late **in**/**on** the evening of July 1.

**In** emphasizes the lateness within the evening period; **on** just says it happened (a) late and (b) during the evening of July 1. In practice, there would be few situations where one of these descriptions would be valid and the other would be invalid.

Comment: COCA certainly has lots of results for "late on": "overran another frontier town late on Thursday", "following an authorized recreation trip to West Yellowstone late on the night of August 12, 1939", "compared to an 11,000-vote edge late on election night". "Late" without "on" is used e.g. "late summer", "late 2008", "late May" but IMO it flows better using "on" with a longer expression as in "late on the previous Saturday evening".

Answer (score 0):

To me this usage of "on" feels incorrect.   It would have been fine if the author had left out the preposition entirely,

> Unconscious since late the previous Saturday evening, Sir Isaac Newton.

In any case the context makes more sense now.  This is an example of what I think is called a *participle phrase*, or perhaps just an *adjectival phrase*.  Since the phrase doesn't contain a verb, the tense is implied by context,

> Isaac Newton, (the person who **has been**) unconscious since late the previous evening.

It's possible the author is mixing this with a related expression, "on the evening of ..."  This is used to give a time frame to isolated events, but not to events that continue from a particular moment in time.

> Isaac Newton died late **on the evening of** March 20th ...

Comment: It's a little unusual to connect both "since late" and "on" to an evening, but one can certainly say "since late on [specific entire day]". For example, in Tom Clancy's "Into the Storm: A Study in Command" (2007): "Since both these areas were outside VII Corps sector, and had been since late on 25 February, there was nothing we could do to stop the units leaving by that route."